# React Navigation useLayoutEffect headerRight gives Typescript error

Tags: typescript, react-navigation

FOllowing React Navigation's [instructions here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/header-buttons/#header-interaction-with-its-screen-component)

I have this in my code:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    function signOut() {
      setUser(undefined);
      navigation.navigate('Search');
    }
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <Button onPress={() => signOut()} title="Log out" type="clear" />,
    });
  }, [navigation, setUser]);
```

I'm getting TypeScript error:

```
Argument of type '{ headerRight: () => JSX.Element; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<BottomTabNavigationOptions>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'headerRight' does not exist in type 'Partial<BottomTabNavigationOptions>'.
```

Any idea why and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the type of the navigator that you are using.  The code in the docs works just fine with a stack or drawer navigator.  With a stack navigator, the types for `navigation.setOptions` are:

```
setOptions(options: Partial<StackNavigationOptions>): void;
```

The [type `StackNavigationOptions`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/7b353a4aeabe204284b358af204caebe1db093c1/packages/stack/src/types.tsx#L266) includes the [type `StackHeaderOptions`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/7b353a4aeabe204284b358af204caebe1db093c1/packages/stack/src/types.tsx#L112) which declares the [`headerRight` property](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/7b353a4aeabe204284b358af204caebe1db093c1/packages/stack/src/types.tsx#L182).

You get an error because you are using a different type of navigator with a different type of options.

```
'headerRight' does not exist in type 'Partial<BottomTabNavigationOptions>'
```

That [type `BottomTabNavigationOptions`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/6ac4d40140189a29d857c4d1203bced6929f7baf/packages/bottom-tabs/src/types.tsx#L79) does not include any header-related types because **bottom tabs don't have a header**.

If you want to set the `headerRight` property then you need to use a navigator type that supports it, like the stack or the [drawer](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/dbe961ba5bb243e8da4d889c3c7dd6ed1de287c4/packages/drawer/src/types.tsx#L150) navigators.